# AudioRecord: Continuously record audio data and simultaneously analyse it

Tags: android, arrays, audiorecord, audio-analysis

I am trying to use an AudioRecord object in android to record audio data into a byte array and simultaneously perform some analysis on the recorded data. But I am unsure how to do it.
If I use the byte array directly the application crashes. I need a byte array as an input for the analysing thread I am relatively new to android development and I would appreciate any help on this topic. 
Thanks

```
byte[] data;
public void Record()throws IOException{
    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,RECORDER_CHANNELS,RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);
    AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);
    recorder.startRecording();        
    isRecording = true;
    boolean flag = true;
    data = new byte[bufferSize];
    while(isRecording){
        try {               
            int result = recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);                
            if(flag){
                Thread analyseThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        theAnalysingFunction();
                    }
                },"AudioRecorder Thread");
                analyseThread.start();
                flag=false;
            }
            if (AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION !=result ) {

            } else if (result == AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION) {
                Log.e("Recording", "Invalid operation error");
                break;
            } else if (result == AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                Log.e("Recording", "Bad value error");
                break;
            } else if (result == AudioRecord.ERROR) {
                Log.e("Recording", "Unknown error");
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Error", "AudioRecord error");

        }
    }       
}
public void theAnalysingFunction(){
    //
    //Analyse the byte array named data
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is multithreading. You try to analyze a buffer. While another thread changes it simultaneously.

About your crash, if U use a byte buffer, make sure U use ENCODING_PCM_8BIT for encoding.